# Google OAuth - How to check that user has already allowed access to my application

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

**Short description:**

If a user has already granted my application OAuth access to their google profile, I want to spare them of having to press "sign in using google" button every time they land on my home page and log them in automatically.

If user has not granted access yet, I want to present them with sign in options page with "sign in using google" button.

**Long description:**

I am implementing Google OAuth flow as described on this link:

[Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)

Just for the clarity, the flow in question is as follows:

1. present (client side) user with "sign in using google" button
2. after user presses the button, redirect them to google's OAuth 2.0 server, where they allow/deny my application to access their google profile
3. if user allows access, google redirects them back to my application
4. my application (server side) uses acquired grant to get access token
5. my application (server side) access user's profile using acquired access token

I want to achieve the following:

If user has already allowed my application access to their google profile before (either on current computer or some other), I want them to have an impression of being signed in to my application (using google) immediately after they navigate to my application's URL. Without having to click anything.

This is at first glance not a problem. To achieve this, I would automate steps 1 and 2 of the flow described above. User would be redirected to google oauth server automatically - without having to press "sign in using google" button - right after they navigates to application's URL. Google in turn immediately redirects user back to my application with a valid grant (again without requiring any input from the user). The rest remains the same. User would have an impression of being logged in immediately .

This approach has a problem though. If user goes to my page for the first time (not having granted my application access before), they would also be redirected to google OAuth page. But since they haven't granted access yet, and didn't press any sing in button, they would and end up staring at google oauth server page confused having no clue, what is going on.

Is there some API, by which I can detect that user has not yet granted access to my app (and I should present him with sing in button first)?

Please, if your solution would involve some API calls, point me to a HTTP/REST API, as I don't use (and do not want use) any higher level OAuth library.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds more like a session management/cookie issue on your app side rather than an OAuth sign-in issue. Also, maintaining session status between devices (or even browsers) is pretty much impossible. What platform does your app use?

Comment: It's AngularJS (client) + Web API (server). I don't believe I am trying to maintain session between devices. The only thing I want to achieve is to log in user automatically if 2 conditions are met: 1. User is logged in google on current computer, 2: user has already approved access to my application (on current computer or any other computer). The fact that user has granted my application access to his google account is not session related. It is stored in their google profile.

Comment: Are you using the Google Sign-in client client-side? If so, after you initialize the GoogleAuth object, you can check and see if the client is already signed in using `isSignedIn.get()` or you can check to see if they've already authorized your application by checking `hasGrantedScopes()` on the GoogleUser returned by `currentUser.get()`. If they're not signed in or haven't granted scopes to your app, don't automate the process.

Comment: @ZanyCadence, thanks for mentioning this option. Would you mind pasting here a URL of home page of aforementioned GoogleAuth library? Thx.

Comment: @TyphoonOfDvina have you solved this problem ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, I'll be testing the solution next weekend (Nov. 21/22). I will inform about results.

Comment: @TyphoonOfDvina I will be waiting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "prompt=none" parameter to your initial OAuth redirect. This way google will not block if user has not logged in or has not granted your app the permissions.

See Chapter 3.1.2.1 of http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#AuthRequest

Short summary of other possible "prompt" values:

- none - will not prompt anything, redirects back with error "login_required" or "interaction_required" if silent login is not possible.
- login - force the login prompt, even when user is logged-in.
- consent - force the consent prompt, even if user has provided consent in the past.
- select_account - present account selection prompt.

Comment: looks like that's what I am looking for. Let me thoroughly read the document and verify the solution.

Comment: @TyphoonOfDvina have you got any idea, I am trying to get the same thing .

Comment: So this really works, thank you @Vilmantas.
However, now I am very confused about relationship of OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect as implemented by google.

In the [official google documentation of OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#redirecting), I used, there is no mention about 'post' parameter and yet, it works. This parameter is clearly part of Open ID and not OAuth 2.0. Then why does it work with OAuth 2.0?

"OpenID Connect 1.0 is a simple identity layer **ON TOP** of the OAuth 2.0 protocol." and not the other way around.

I am truly confused.

Comment: Yes, "OpenID *Connect*" is an OAuth2 extension. Do not confuse it with the original OpenID.